# Searching through a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I'm having trouble getting my program to search through my list for a duplicate ID. I need to add a new student to my list, but if the inputed ID is already being used the program needs to print that the ID is already in use and is not able to be added to the list. My list:

```
ID, NAME, MAJOR, SCORE = 0, 1, 2, 3
s_list = [
    ['01', 'Smith', 'CS', 100],
    ['02', 'Jones', 'CS', 90],
    ['03', 'Anderson', 'Math', 80],
    ['04', 'Johnson', 'Bio', 99],
]
def stu_list(s_list):
    print('Student List:')
    print('Id'.ljust(5), 'Name'.ljust(12), 'Major'.ljust(9), 'Score')
    for ID, NAME, MAJOR, SCORE in s_list:
        print(f'{ID:6}{NAME:13}{MAJOR:8}{SCORE:5}')
    print('--End of List--\n')
```

UPDATED:

```
def insert_stu(s_list):
    print('Adding a student.')
    n_ID = input('ID: ')
    n_NAME = input('Name: ')
    n_MAJOR = input('Major: ')
    n_SCORE = int(input('Score: '))

    id_list = []
    for stud in s_list:
        id_list.append(stud[0])

        if n_ID in id_list:
            print(f'{n_ID} already exists, unable to add student')
        elif n_ID not in s_list:
                new_stu = [n_ID, n_NAME, n_MAJOR, n_SCORE]
                s_list.append(new_stu)
                print(f'Not Found \nAdding to the list.')
        stu_list(s_list)
        return insert_stu(s_list)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Adding a student.
ID: 02
Name: Cris
Major: math
Score: 23
Not Found 
Adding to the list.
Student List:
Id    Name         Major     Score
01    Smith        CS        100
02    Jones        CS         90
03    Anderson     Math       80
04    Johnson      Bio        99
09    new          cs         90
02    Cris         math       23   ##still adding duplicate id's
--End of List--
```

When I run the function it adds the new student regardless if the inputed ID is already in use. I think the problem I am having is getting the `ID` variable to link with the first column in the s_list ('01', '02',...).

Comment: @Mohammed Shabeer kp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the comparison on the full student entry instead of just the ID.
You could fix by changing the code below:

```
for i in s_list:            ##not searching list for duplicate
    if n_ID == i:
```

to:

```
for i in s_list:            ##not searching list for duplicate
    if n_ID == i[0]:
```

or just using a dictionary instead of list.

EDIT
Your second version builds the id list at the same time of the check so the for loop adds the existing student because it did not yet get to add it to the id list. You're adding ID 02 because the id in the first iteration of the loop is 01. I'd change to this (not the most efficient code, just trying to make minimal changes to your existing code):

```
for stud in s_list:
    id_list.append(stud[0])

if n_ID in id_list:
    print(f'{n_ID} already exists, unable to add student')
elif n_ID not in s_list:
    new_stu = [n_ID, n_NAME, n_MAJOR, n_SCORE]
    s_list.append(new_stu)
    print(f'Not Found \nAdding to the list.')
stu_list(s_list)
return s_list
```

Comment: I tried this but the duplicate is still getting added??

Comment: You have the return statement in the if statement calling the function again. Did you want to just: return(s_list)?

Comment: Yes return the s_list with the new student, but if the student ID is a duplicate I want it to print that the new student could not be added, and to try adding the student again. Would it be best to use a while loop?

Comment: While could be a solution, just be careful not to get stuck if the user never inputs a new ID and also handle the case there are no more new IDs. I don't know the usecase for your function, you may want to call the function again from outside if needed after you make the checks. In any case do not make the recursive function call you now have, just return s_list.

Comment: see updated answer based on your last version of the code, pay attention to the indentations and the removal of the recursive call in return

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work, because you are comparing the id with the full record about the student.

```
for i in s_list:      # i is the full record about the student   
   if n_ID == i[0]:   # i[0] is the student's id
      print(f'{n_ID} already exists, unable to add student')
      return add_stu(s_list)

# If the for loop finished, then no match was found
s_list.append(new_stu)
stu_list(s_list)
print('Student added')
return add_stu(s_list)
```

Code like this will work, but it's recursive - you call add_stu() from inside itself. Most probably it's not what you want. Usually such tasks are performed by making a loop, in which you ask for the user input and break the loop if the user input is correct:

```
def add_stu(s_list):
    print('Adding a student.')
    while(true):
        n_ID = input('ID: ')
        n_NAME = input('Name: ')
        n_MAJOR = input('Major: ')
        n_SCORE = int(input('Score: '))
        student_exists = false
        for i in s_list: 
             if n_ID == i[0]:
                  student_exists = true
                  break
        if not student_exists:
             new_stu = [n_ID, n_NAME, n_MAJOR, n_SCORE]
             s_list.append(new_stu)
             print('Student added')
             return s_list
        print(f'{n_ID} already exists, unable to add student')
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to search for duplicate ID and further processing.

you can create a list of student ID's then check for duplicate in that list.

```py
def insert_stu(s_list):
    print('Adding a student.')
    n_ID = input('ID: ')
    n_NAME = input('Name: ')
    n_MAJOR = input('Major: ')
    n_SCORE = int(input('Score: '))

    id_list = []
    for stud in s_list:      # creating list of ID
        id_list.append(stud[0])

    if n_ID in id_list:      # searching list for duplicate
        print(f'{n_ID} already exists, unable to add student')
    elif n_ID not in s_list:
        new_stu = [n_ID, n_NAME, n_MAJOR, n_SCORE]
        s_list.append(new_stu)
        print(f'Not Found \nAdding to the list.')
    stu_list(s_list)
    return insert_stu(s_list)
```

Comment: I tried running this but it still added a duplicate ID. Did I place something in the wrong place? I updated my post the new function and also posted the output that I am getting.